# What is the default Kernel Governor in Stock Samsung Galaxy Mega Android ROM?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung, kernel, stock-rom, overclocking

I have rooted my phone recently and just installed ROM Toolbox which has several Governors available. It is using OnDemand by default, but I switched to Interactive. I just need to be as close to default settings in order to maintain stability.

Btw, when I am using a third party app to change CPU Freqs, ROM Toolbox in this case, It seems to be a bit laggy. Is this normal?

Comment: Are we talking Nexus-stock or manufacturer-stock? The "Galaxy S" tag here leads me to think that this is question is specific to the Galaxy S. If this is the case, coult you please edit the question to specify that you want to know the default governor for the Galaxy S?

Comment: running galaxy mega stock rom and using Rom Toolbox to change cpu governors/freqs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the default governor for the Galaxy Mega. However, there's an easy way to determine your *current* governor. Rebooting the phone (Unless you ticked the option in ROM Manager and/or other apps to persist governor selections through reboot) will reset it back to its default setting.

You can find your current governor by running the following command in an adb shell or terminal emulator:

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

Chances are your default governor is indeed ondemand. It is commonly used as the default governor on many Android devices, and seems like one that Samsung would like to use.

Comment: thanks for the oneliner tip, it's indeed on demand. However, I have disabled the Rom Toolbox overclocking tool. Kinda makes my device "laggy"

Comment: Glad it worked! It's also interesting that using the tool didn't work well, but not particularly surprising.